# Windows server 2012 R2 drivers for Fujitsu CELSIUS R930 Power

Tags: hardware, windows, drivers

I'm trying to install Windows Server 2012 R2 on a Fujitsu CELSIUS R930 Power workstation and have problems finding the right drivers.

Fujitsu "tech support" won't help me - they don't support server installation on their workstations and their driver installation software won't run under Windows Server 2012 R2.

Do anybody know a Fujitsu server that have the same motherboard as the CELSIUS R930 Power?

I have trouble installing the PCI bus and the SAS controller.

Answer (score 4):

First thing : it doesn't look like this motherboard is used in anything besides CELSIUS workstations. Google search for `site:fujitsu.com D3118` doesn't show anything else, so no - it does not appear that this board is used in any server hardware. There are some big differences between true workstations and most server hardware, they are usually optimized for different things.

Second thing : there are many reasons that professional systems administrators don't like to do unsupported things for production environments, which is what this site likes to focus on. You're trying to use non-server hardware as a server, and the vendor won't help you. These should be big red flashing lights for you, if this is for a production environment.

Imagine that you could get it to work and put a business service on there. Then you find a problem with performance, and want to go to the vendor for help. You'll be out of luck.